# How do I create a movie DVD?

Tags: software-recommendation, dvd

I would like to create a movie DVD that contains some pictures and small movies. I'm not after anything too fancy, just the ability to add some music, create a title screen and add a menu. Basically, something like [Windows Movie Maker](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker).

What would be my best option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another good alternative to Windows Movie Maker is [OpenShot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) which has more features than pitivi but still manages to have a simple, easy to use interface. A good program for writing videos to DVD (With support for titles and menus) is [DeVeDe](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html).

Both of these applications are available to install from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: K3b is also good at writing DVD movies.

Comment: I used DeVeDe and it got the job done!

Answer (score 4):

There's a new software for authoring DVD's, it is named [Bombono](http://www.bombono.org).
Just give a:

```
sudo apt-get install bombono-dvd
```

Comment: tried in Oneiric beta2 but I think the interface is not compatible with GTK3... can't browse source files..

Answer (score 2):

I love OpenShot and DeVeDe, but I would like to mention [DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/) too. ;) And if you want to create photo slideshows, then go for 2ManDVD.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a video DVD using Brasero CD-creator, which you can find in the multimedia menu.

If you launch it, you can select 'make a video CD/DVD'. 
Then you can add movies to it.

If you want to edit your movies, you can use Pitivi, also found in the multimedia menu.

Comment: I tried Brasero for creating DVD but it requires vcdimager and mplex plugin, and I don't find any "mplex" package...