# How do I create a movie DVD to be played on a TV

Tags: dvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a movie DVD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3617/how-do-i-create-a-movie-dvd)

I have all these DVD rips on my computer, and I want to put them on a DVD to play on my TV, as my laptop doesn't have a HDMI port. What is the best way to do this? I have Ubuntu 12.04. Iv'e tried using Brasero, but i don't get any sound, just the image. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[DeVeDe](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/devede)**. I experimented a bit with a few options and DeVeDe was the best I found. It installs some KDE components but the gnome alternatives were not as good.